I can't install NVIDIA Quadro M2000M driver in Ubuntu Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS Kernal 6.8.0-45-generic
Additional Drivers:
NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM [Quadro M2000M]
The device is using a manually-installed driver.
  nvidia-driver-550 (proprietary, tested)
  nvidia-driver-535-server (proprietary)
  nvidia-driver-470-server (proprietary)
  nvidia-driver-470 (proprietary)
  nvidia-driver-535 (proprietary)
  Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
There's a red indicator next to the option "Continue using a manually installed driver" suggesting that this is the current setting to continue installing the driver (the driver restarted the system after downloading), but the Apply Changes button is disabled and I can't select another option because all of them are disabled too.
The note down there says: A proprietary driver has private code that Ubuntu developers can't review or improve. Security and other updates are dependent on the driver vendor.

The Nvidia site has the 550.120 driver for Linux. I suppose you could remove all packages with "nvidia" in their name, then try the driver selection process again while running the known nouveau driver.
